# How to get the Logical Children of a RowDefinition?

Tags: wpf, rowdefinition

I have Extended the `RowDefinition` as `RowDefinitionExtended` and In that, when can i get the `LogicalChildren` belongs to this `RowDefinition`. I mean in which override can i get the `LogicalChildren`?

```
public class RowDefinitionExtended : RowDefinition
{
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        Loaded += OnRowDefinitionExtendedLoaded;
    }


    void OnRowDefinitionExtendedLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = GetUIParentCore() as Grid;
        if (parent == null) return;

        if (parent.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == parent.RowDefinitions.IndexOf(this)).All(ctrl => ctrl.Visibility != Visibility.Visible))
            Height = new GridLength(0);
    }

}
```

What my requirement is, I need to check all the `LogicalChildren` to its `Visibility` and Change its `Height` accordingly.

How could i do this? Any idea?

**Update:**

Code has been updated, On Load I could do this and it works fine. But my problem is, am changing the controls visibility after load... So is there any notification while changing the Visibility? am looking a event when the layout updated like..

Any event can i use it for?

Comment: What do you expect to be contained in the LogicalChildren collection of a RowDefinition? At least, the child elements of a Grid are *not* the children of a RowDefinition.

Comment: You could just set the initial Height of the RowDefinition to `Auto`. When the Visibily of all Grid children in that row change to `Collapsed`, the row will disappear automatically.

Comment: @Clemens: I have some cases that to set the Visibility as Hidden..

Comment: Ok, you might subscribe to the IsVisibleChanged event of each child in the specific row.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that by means of a derived RowDefinition, but this little helper method should do the job (if your intention was to get all child elements in a certain row of a `Grid`):

```
public static IEnumerable<UIElement> ChildrenInRow(Grid grid, int row)
{
    return grid.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the IsVisibleChanged handler for each element in the row when the row is loaded.

When the visibility changed, you could do whatever you need

```
 public class RowDefinitionExtended : RowDefinition
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInitialized(e);
            Loaded += OnRowDefinitionExtendedLoaded;
        }


        void OnRowDefinitionExtendedLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var parent = GetUIParentCore() as Grid;
            if (parent == null) return;

            //Subscribe to the IsVisibleChanged handler for each element in the row
            var ElementInGridRow = parent.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == parent.RowDefinitions.IndexOf(this));
            foreach (var element in ElementInGridRow)
            {
                element.IsVisibleChanged+=new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnChildrenIsVisibleChanged);
            }
        }

        private void OnChildrenIsVisibleChanged(object sender,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement element = sender as UIElement;

            //Do stuff...
            var parent = GetUIParentCore() as Grid;
            if (parent.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == parent.RowDefinitions.IndexOf(this)).All(ctrl => ctrl.Visibility != Visibility.Visible))
                Height = new GridLength(0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this best way to have a handler for all the controls? Its affects the performance right...

Comment: I thinks it's the best way... try and tell me.